# .Net Core Enumeration problem using FromRoute and EnumMember

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having a somewhat similar issue to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4008 that I'd like help with it at all possible.

For the url http://localhost:51049/api/values/proof_of_address the route should evaluate proof_of_address as ProofOfAddress in the enum below.

I've attempted to follow the example in the link above but regardless of what I put in the url I get the first value in the enumeration. My code is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None;
        opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    });
}

[HttpGet("{documenttype}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get([FromRoute] DocumentType documenttype)
{
    return documenttype.ToString();
}

public class CustomEnumConverter<T> : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var s = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(@"""" + value.ToString() + @"""");
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(CustomEnumConverter<DocumentType>))]
public enum DocumentType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "passport")]
    Passport,

    [EnumMember(Value = "proof_of_address")]
    ProofOfAddress
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `CanConvertFrom` to return `true`

```
public class CustomEnumConverter<T> : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var s = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(@"""" + value.ToString() + @"""");
    }
}
```